# NHibernate Linq where clause: value in collection

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I am wondering can I do a where clause that takes in a collection?

```
List<string> myStrings = new List<strings> {"1", "2"};

session.Query<Table>().Where(x => x.Id == myStrings).ToList();
```

I basically want to get all rows from my db table that match everything in that query.

```
session.Query<Table>().Where(x => x.Id == myStrings[0]).ToList();
session.Query<Table>().Where(x => x.Id == myStrings[1]).ToList();
session.Query<Table>().Where(x => x.Id == myStrings[N]).ToList();
```

So thats what I would have to do right now. I would probably through that in a for loop but that is alot of queryies and I rather just do one query.

Or do I have to use the nhibernate create query syntax

```
var query = "Select * From Where In (:Id)";
session.CreateQuery(query)SetParameter("Id",myStrings) // not sure if I have to something like .ExecuteUpdate(); but just for select instead
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session.Query<Table>().Where(x => myString.All(s => x.Id == s));
```

Comment: I have this session.Query<Table>().Where(x => myString.All(s => x.myString == s)).ToList(); and I get "Specified method is not supported." I also tried what you had an got that "==" could not be applied to operands of type "Table"

Comment: Oh, should've been `x.Id`. However, if NHibernate is unable to access the `myString` collection, you have a problem - and I'm not really involved with NHibernate to give you advise. Sorry.

Comment: @Femaref - So this is a nhibernate issue then?

Comment: Sadly, it is. The NHibernate LINQ libary probably isn't that advanced. In entity framework or linq to sql this would work. You'll probably have to stick with the create query syntax.

Comment: first, nhibernate linq is not so advanced as ms one (ie: you can't do Convert.ToInt32 in the linq expression). anyway, i'm sure you can use either ALL or ANY

Comment: yes, you can use `All` and `Any`, but you can't use it on an object **outside** the lambda (the `myStrings` list in this case), with already present objects in the lambda, like a referenced sequence in a `Table` object.

Comment: @frabiacca - I just ended up using HQL. Seem like nhibernate linq just can't do these things yet.

Answer (score 4):

```
session.Query<Table>().Where(x => myStrings.Contains(s => x.Id));
```

Comment: but would that not match parts? Like if I am searching for '5' and I have these ids(5,500,100). Won't that match 5 & 500?

Comment: No. It should search for the "Table" elements which have matching IDs in the supplied collection.

Comment: @chobo2: this should be the accepted answer since it works as you asked, `All()`, `Any()` give unsupported exception.

Answer (score 0):

you should use Any or All extension method on your collection

Comment: could you provide an example or is the same as Femaref?